Does K-means also works for classifying continuous functions?
I am trying to classify a sample of different functions with polynomial characteristics.
I chose K-means since I am a bit familiar with the algorithm, but I am trying to see if it is actually valid to use in my case.
I have uploaded some samples I got when trying to classify into 4 groups:

Most of the graphs look like the upper and corner left ones.
If I would start from scratch (without using K-means), I would compare each set of graphs and look at the differences per data point and then divide/group them based on the smallest differences per pair and take the average difference per set. The main thing in that case is that there might be a 'big' difference at some data point which won't be visible by taking the average.
How would my simple approach compare to the results I got by using K-means?

Needs more information on what your inputs are and how you are outputting these graphs. Perhaps provide some example polynomials and what you expect and what you get - perhaps that's what you've tried to do but it isn't obvious as you haven't mentioned which polynomial , and how the graphs represent the output of your k-means.
